# Vertical and Horizontal Line in a Matplotlib table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot a DataFrame using Matplotlib. The x and y values of the horizontal and vertical lines depend on the width and height of the first index. However, I found that the axhline is plotting the horizontal line at y=0. Whereas, axvline is doing correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tbl = ax.table(
    cellText=df.values,
    rowLabels=df.index,
    colLabels=df.columns,
    cellLoc="center",
    loc="center",
    fontsize=20,
    edges="open",
)
ax.axvline(x=tbl[1, -1].get_width(), color="blue", lw=1)
ax.axhline(y=tbl[1, -1].get_bbox().ymax, color="red", lw=1)
ax.axis("off")
```

[image]

I realized if I hardcoded the y value, I have no issues plotting the line

```
# ...
ax.axhline(y=0.6578, color="red", lw=1)
# ...
```

[image]

How can I make axhline work correctly using the first index height location?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is that the table needs to be **drawn** first before you draw the axhline. If you add `plt.draw()` AFTER the `ax.table(..)` and BEFORE the `axvline()` and `axhline()`, it will work..

[image]

Full updated code... (just one extra line :-))

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

tbl = ax.table(
    cellText=df.values,
    rowLabels=df.index,
    colLabels=df.columns,
    cellLoc="center",
    loc="center",
    fontsize=20,
    edges="open",
)

plt.draw()  ## The added line

ax.axvline(x=tbl[1, -1].get_width(), color="blue", lw=1)
ax.axhline(y=tbl[1, -1].get_bbox().ymax, color="red", lw=1)
ax.axis("off")
```

Comment: Thanks @Redox for your response. It makes completely sense now that you pointed this out. I can generate a figure to access formatting details before the final rendering

Answer (score 2):

You can also control the dimensions of the figure and axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

# Set dimensions
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=df.shape)
ax.axis([0, df.shape[1], df.shape[0], -1]) # xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax

tbl = ax.table(
    cellText=df.values,
    rowLabels=df.index,
    colLabels=df.columns,
    cellLoc="center",
    # loc="center",  # <- don't let matplotlib handle the position
    bbox=(0, 0, 1, 1),  # <- Force the bounding box
    fontsize=20,
    edges="open",
)

ax.axvline(x=0, color="blue", lw=1)
ax.axhline(y=0, color="red", lw=1)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. This answer is also useful in case I need more control of the dimensions.